# How to disable modal closing when clicking outside? [Materialize]

Tags: html, materialize

I have a materialize modal and I would like to know how to disable the closing of it when you click away. Follow my code:

```
<div id="hscal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
        <h1 class="h4">Histórico de Calibração</h1>
        <div class="modal-content">
          <table id="bodymodal" class="highlight centered"></table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button
            class="btn waves-effect waves-light col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-2 close-modal"
            type="reset"
            id="fx"
            name="action"
            href="#"
            v-on:click="exitModal"
          >Fechar
            <i id="iconbtn" class="material-icons right">clear</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this and many other modifications during [initialisation](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#options):

```
// with jQuery

$('.modal').modal({
   dismissible: false
});

// Vanilla JS

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, {
       dismissible: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, you helpned very much!